# Onclick function on div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function for getting records from database on keyup event.
Here is my code:

```
function displaySearch(key) {
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"searchprofile.php",
    data:{
        k:key
    },
    success:function(data){
       var details_arr=data.split("+");
        $('.searchresult').empty();
        for(var i=0;i<details_arr.length-1;i++){
            $('.searchresult').append("<div class='profile' id='searchprofile'><img class='profilepic' src='images/profile.jpg'/><div class='doctorname'><div class='pname' onclick='saveName("+details_arr[i]+")'>"+details_arr[i]+"</div></div></div>");
            $('.searchresult').show();
            $('.searchresult .profile').show();
        }
        details_arr.length=0;
    }
});
}
```

But i am getting javascript error here saying "Unexpected token ILLEGAL". 
How do i give the onclick function with the value of details_arr[i]?
Please help.

Comment: "unexpected token ILLEGAL" means you have a syntax error in your code.

Comment: Perhaps you have a syntax error in your previous code? The code you have posted is correct, syntactically.

Comment: `$('.searchresult')` could be cached for performance.

Comment: Using `onclick='saveName("+details_arr[i]+")'` is ugly, especially in dynamically generated code. It would be much cleaner if you attached the handler with jQuery.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak This error is at line 1 i.e at the <html> tag. I have php code before that.

Comment: Then show us what the browser gets, complete up to that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the onclick function working. :)

Instead of appending the div everytime, i just editted my php page by adding the html i needed in the data that is returned in ajax.

Answer (score 4):

As you have jQuery, you really shouldn't inline code. As you see it makes it more difficult to handle quotes inside quoted strings (yes, you're missing quotes around your argument to `saveName`).

You may do this :

```
  (function(i){
      $('.searchresult').append(
        "<div class='profile' id='searchprofile'>"
        + "<img class='profilepic' src='images/profile.jpg'/>"
        + "<div class='doctorname'>"
        + "<div id=someId class='pname'>"+details_arr[i] // <- give some Id
        +"</div></div></div>"
      );
      $('#someId').click(function(){saveName(details_arr[i])});
  })(i);
  $('.searchresult').show();
```

Note that I used a closure to ensure that i has the needed value in the callback (not the value at end of iteration).

Be careful with the split: on most browsers `"+aaa".split('+')` makes `["", "aaa"]` and as you don't iterate up to the end of the array, this sample string would made you iterate on nothing.

Comment: @ChetanaKestikar and still there is one less bug in the code. Upvoting.

Comment: @ChetanaKestikar Why don't you loop over the whole array ? Is that a bug ?

Comment: @dystroy Hey i tried your code again, this time i just added an alert before 'saveName(details_arr[i])'. The value of details_arr[i] i am getting is 'undefined'. And i did not understand the loop over idea. Can u please explain?

Comment: @dystroy To avoid getting the blank record, in for loop i gave the condition 'i<details_arr-1'. I think that overcomes the empty record problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
function openNow(x)
{
    var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/OnFriends.php")%>'
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pageUrl + '/CreateNew',
        data: '{k: "'+ x +'"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data)
        {
            <---Now Do Your Code Hear--->
        }
        });
}
```

CreateNew is my web service what i created in .php file

Comment: now this AJAX request will execute the 'CreateNew' function of OnFriends.php file and return the result as 'data'

Comment: So CreateNew is a function in the php file called? I did not know we could give the function name in url.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But i am getting the data from the php page. The issue is i am not able to get the onclick function result on div.

Comment: not just a function... that must be a Static Function (WebService)

Comment: if you never created a web service theGoogle it "How to create a web service in php"

Comment: ok.. fine..
just try once onclick='saveName("+details_arr[i]+");' insteade of onclick='saveName("+details_arr[i]+")'

Comment: i think " ; " is the reason

Comment: then try to nest you div within an anchor tag and add the onclick event to anchor tag..
that will work i m sure

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like that
`bare in mind ID must be unique inside a document (HTML Page)`
because the content is generated on the fly; it's better to use the JQuery "on"

```
   $(".pname").on("click", function (event) {
       saveName($(this).text());
   });
```

event handler to bind the click event

```
function displaySearch(key){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "searchprofile.php",
        data: {
            k: key
        },

        success: function(data) {
            var details_arr = data.split("+");

            var searchResults = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < details_arr.length - 1; i++) {
                searchResults += "<div class='profile'>" +
                    "<img class='profilepic' src='images/profile.jpg'/>" +
                    "<div class='doctorname'>" +
                    "<div class='pname'>" + details_arr[i] +
                    "</div></div></div>";

            }
            $('.searchresult').html(searchResults).show();
        }
    });
}

$(".pname").on("click", function (event) {
    saveName($(this).text());
});
```

use the Jquery html to replace everything inside searchresult outside the loop that way it 
will be called once not details_arr.length - 1 times

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. But this is not working. The onclick event on $(".pname") is not working.

Comment: can you give us the website address to debug it for you or you can use jsfiddle.com

Comment: Okay... But this will take me sometime.

Answer (score 0):

you should tell the line at which you are getting error

i think you did not specified you web service in ajax call at...
        "url:"searchprofile.php"

Comment: @Pankaj I don't understand your point. Maybe you could make it clearer ?

Comment: first you have to create a web service in searchprofile.php
the write like this...

url:"searchprofile.php/<--your service name-->"

Comment: It depends on how your page is made. It's fine to have a page directly answering `searchprofile.php?data=33`.

Comment: @dystroy you are suggesting him to send data as Querystring that's not the right way...  data may be confidential

Comment: If it's confidential, then use SSL, don't try to hide the data in a post body. And please don't try to say it's always wrong to use parameters in an URL...

Comment: using parameter in URL may be convenient
  but why if you are using 'data:...'